# Detox Exceeded timeout of 600000ms while handling jest-circus "setup" event amazon codebuild

Tags: android, jestjs, aws-codebuild, detox

detox test -c android.emu.release --workers * --debug-synchronization 500
detox[3298] INFO:  [test.js] DETOX_CONFIGURATION="android.emu.release" DETOX_DEBUG_SYNCHRONIZATION=500 DETOX_FORCE_ADB_INSTALL=false DETOX_READ_ONLY_EMU=false DETOX_REPORT_SPECS=true DETOX_START_TIMESTAMP=*6*95*2452784 DETOX_USE_CUSTOM_LOGGER=true jest --config e2e/config.json --testNamePattern '^((?!:ios:).)*$' --maxWorkers * e2e

detox[33*0] ERROR: Exceeded timeout of 600000ms while handling jest-circus "setup" event
detox[33*0] INFO:  xxx is assigned to undefined
detox[33*0] INFO:  xxx: should have a login screen
detox[33*0] INFO:  xxx: should have login screen [SKIPPED]
detox[33*0] INFO:  xxx: should have network error screen
detox[33*0] INFO:  xxx: should have network error screen [SKIPPED]

detox[33*0] ERROR: Aborted detox.init() execution, and now running detox.cleanup()

HINT: Most likely, your test runner is tearing down the suite due to the timeout error
detox[33*0] WARN:  at node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/index.js:27*:*5
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
emulator: INFO: boot completed
emulator: INFO: boot time 7694*4 ms
emulator: Increasing screen off timeout, logcat buffer size to 2M.
emulator: Revoking microphone permissions for Google App.
emulator: VERBOSE: System.cpp:*57*: Timed out with running command |/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -e shell settings put system screen_off_timeout 2*47483647 |

Noted: It works normally when I run on my macbook, but failed on Amazon Codebuild, any advice on this?

Comment: Did you find any solution?